# md-content does not consume full height of the parent element

Tags: angularjs, layout, angular-material

```
<md-content flex class="md-padding page-content">
    <div ui-view flex layout="column">   
       <div class="center" layout="row" flex>
        <md-content layout="column" flex="30">
          <md-list-item ng-repeat="entity in vm.entities">
            <md-checkbox ng-model="entity.selected"></md-checkbox>
            <p>{{entity.info}}</p>
            <md-icon class="md-secondary"
                     ng-click="doSecondaryAction($event)" aria-label="Chat">message</md-icon>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-content>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
        <md-content layout="column" flex="70">
          Details here!
        </md-content> 
      </div> 
     </div>   
 </md-content>
```

In my code above, the outermost md-content occupies the complete page; however with the ui-view gived column layout and flex class, I expected it to occupy the complete height of the page, however it occupies the height consumed by the content only.

Can you please help with the error in the code, so ui-view can occupy the complete page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VKXWwX)

You need to utilise `layout-fill`. From the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options)

[image]

In order for this to work an upper element must occupy the full screen. In the above example it is `<body>`.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill>
  <md-content layout-fill flex class="md-padding page-content">
    <div ui-view flex layout="column" layout-fill>   
      <div class="center" layout="row" flex>
        <md-content id="list" layout="column" flex="30">
          <md-list-item ng-repeat="entity in vm.entities" flex="none">
            <md-checkbox ng-model="entity.selected"></md-checkbox>
            <p>{{entity.info}}</p>
            <md-icon class="md-secondary"
                     ng-click="doSecondaryAction($event)" aria-label="Chat">message</md-icon>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-content>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
        <md-content id="details" layout="column" flex="70">
          Details here!
        </md-content> 
      </div> 
    </div>   
  </md-content>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page-content {
  background: yellow
}

#list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hey @camden_kid thanks for the answer. However, what I was trying to achieve is the separate scroll/fill for the list at the left and the detail panel at the right. Like in your codepen, both are same height. Is there a way I can make the list take full height irrespective of elements in the list(the vertical divider would be full height) and both sections have separate scroll for themselves.

Comment: @user1242321 See the updated CodePen. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I could not see the scroll in the list part there....my questoin was suppose the list has 100 items...so only the list part should scroll...while detail part remain stationary!

Comment: ...this is the problem i was looking the answer for. I can see the css did the trick here...and I was trying to achieve this just with layout and flex. My bad...Thanks man!

Comment: @user1242321 Glad to be of help.